# Shopify - Run custom script on login success

Tags: shopify

I want to run a custom script tag after user successfully login to my Shopify store.
Basically I want to have to take control when login result comes, so that I can run my custom script.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Means to say if the customer is login then the code runs?

Comment: @Onkar right.. if there is any way we can do that?

Comment: {% if customer %}{% endif %} wrap the code inside the condition, and it runs. when the customer is logged in to the website. otherwise not.